# does included file contain files included by it?

Tags: php, class, object, include

I've got this **source_folder/config.php** file:

```
<?php


$config['database'] = array (
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'user' => 'root',
  'pass' => '',
  'db' => 'game'
);

?>
```

This **source_folder/class/core.class.php** file:

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'config.php';

function __autoload($sName) {
    $aName = explode('_',$sName);
    if($aName[0] == 'Model')
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'class/model/' . strtolower($aName[1]) . '.class.php';
    elseif($aName[0] == 'View')
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'class/view/' . strtolower($aName[1]) . '.class.php';
    elseif($aName[0] == 'Controller')
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'class/controller/' . strtolower($aName[1]) . '.class.php';
    elseif($aName[0] == 'Core')
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'class/' . strtolower($aName[1]) . '.class.php';
}

class Core {

}
```

And this **source_folder/class/config.class.php** file:

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'class/core.class.php';

/**
 * Description of config
 *
 * @author Lysy
 */
class Core_Config extends Core {

    static function GetConfigArray($name) {
        return $config[$name];
    }
}

?>
```

When I put `var_dump($config['database']);` into **core.class.php** the result is dump of the variable. But when I put `var_dump(Core_Config::GetConfigArray('database'));` anywhere it dumps as *NULL*. Where is the problem? Is **config.php** included in **core.class.php** also included in **config.class.php** as it includes **core.class.php**? From what I know it should be, but it appears that it don't.
**EDIT:** I also tried to put `var_dump($config['database']);` into **config.class.php** but it also dumps as *NULL*.

**EDIT 2:** I solved it using

```
class Core {

    static public function getWholeConfig() {
        global $config;
        return $config;
    }

}
```

in **core.class.php** file and

```
static function GetConfigArray($name) {
    $config = Core::getWholeConfig();
    return $config[$name];
}
```

in **config.class.php** file but still I don't understand why the last file doesn't see the `$config` variable. I mean not in the class scope, but anywhere, this variable is included in **core.class.php** and though **core.class.php** is included in **config.class.php** the variable itself is not. Why?

Comment: Read up on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: It's about availability of variables in functions, I understand that I can't return `$config[$name]` because variable is declared outside of class' and method's scope. But why when I try to dump the variable outside the class in the same file it dumps as *NULL*?

Comment: The presence of your $config array in the actual global scope depends on wherefrom the include script was invoked. Included scripts aren't run in the global scope per default. The autoloader has a local function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place config as a return variable to a function as such

```
function getConfig(){
   $config['database'] = array (
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'user' => 'root',
     'pass' => '',
     'db' => 'game'
   );
   return $config;
}
```

Then in your class you can use:

```
   $config = getConfig();
   return $config[$name];
```

---

I put `var_dump($config);` at the top of **both** config.class and core.class. If I simply load config.class in my browser, I get

```
array (size=1)
  'database' => 
    array (size=4)
      'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
      'user' => string 'root' (length=4)
      'pass' => string '' (length=0)
      'db' => string 'game' (length=4)

array (size=1)
  'database' => 
    array (size=4)
      'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
      'user' => string 'root' (length=4)
      'pass' => string '' (length=0)
      'db' => string 'game' (length=4)
```

Comment: I don't want any functions inside the **config.php** file, but I solved it though, thanks. Anyway my problem is something else, could you look up my last edit?

Comment: I updated my post with my results. It is visible in any file that it is included in as long as it is not within a function or class.

Comment: I get different results, maybe it's the matter of my **php.ini** settings. Thanks for help anyway, I'm getting better and better everyday at this :)